# Adding values of nsarray to another one

Tags: ios, nsarray

So I have a nsarray (there will be lots of those) and I want to add its values to the main NSMutableArray. And I wonder is there any way to do this without using cycles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `[mutableArray addObjectsFromArray: otherArray]`

Answer (score 1):

There's an `addObjectsFromArray:` method in `NSMutableArray`. Works?

Answer (score 0):

Sure

```
addObjectsFromArray: your NSArray
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many cycles this takes, but you can add object from an array with addObjectsFromArray.

```
[mainMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:anotherArray];
```